# How to split JavaScript mult-dimension array and get last array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with the following time-series data. How can I split the array into intervals of 60 milliseconds(not greater than) and get the last array?

```
[
[1619932533,1781.85],
[1619932540,1781.72],
[1619932554,1781.99],
[1619932559,1783.84],
[1619932564,1783.02],
[1619932567,1780.38],
[1619932571,1780.52],
[1619932577,1780.38],
[1619932580,1783.07],
[1619932581,1782.17],
[1619932581,1782.17],
[1619932601,1782.95],
[1619932612,1782.7],
[1619932614,1782.82],
[1619932626,1782.82],
[1619932653,1784.12],
.....
]
```

I need the final data like this?

```
[
[1619932533,1781.85],
[1619932581,1782.17],
[1619932653,1784.12]
]
```

**split based on the first value 1619932533 and +60 and goes on....*

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. Add a loop, compare the current value with previous item in the loop and last item in the output.

Comment: First time is `17:58:52.533` and last time is `17:58:52.653` - there are not 60 seconds between them. Do you mean milliseconds?

Comment: @mplungjan `1619932533 + 60` is `1619932593`. The largest number in that range is `1619932581`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this? I only get two that are 60 milliseconds apart

```js
const data = [
[1619932533,1781.85],
[1619932540,1781.72],
[1619932554,1781.99],
[1619932559,1783.84],
[1619932564,1783.02],
[1619932567,1780.38],
[1619932571,1780.52],
[1619932577,1780.38],
[1619932580,1783.07],
[1619932581,1782.17],
[1619932581,1782.17],
[1619932601,1782.95],
[1619932612,1782.7],
[1619932614,1782.82],
[1619932626,1782.82],
[1619932653,1784.12]
]

const times = data.reduce((acc,arr) => {
  const [d,val] = arr;
  if (acc.length===0) acc.push(arr)
  else if (d - acc[acc.length-1][0] >= 60) acc.push(arr)
  return acc
},[])
console.log(times)
```

Comment: If `d - acc[acc.length-1][0] >= 60`, you need to get `data[i-1]` and push that to the output (You'd have to the third `i` parameter to reduce callback)

Comment: Why? acc[acc.length-1] contains the last saved value from data

Comment: The condition is correct. The item that needs to be pushed to `acc` is the previous item in the `data` array.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not get it. Please post your own answer to show the correct values according to you. I did just wake up so perhaps I’m too sleepy

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use this code.

```
var myObj, curr_time;
myObj = [[1619932533,1781.85],
         [1619932540,1781.72],
         [1619932554,1781.99],
         [1619932559,1783.84],
         [1619932564,1783.02],
         [1619932567,1780.38],
         [1619932571,1780.52],
         [1619932577,1780.38],
         [1619932580,1783.07],
         [1619932581,1782.17],
         [1619932581,1782.17],
         [1619932601,1782.95],
         [1619932612,1782.7],
         [1619932614,1782.82],
         [1619932626,1782.82],
         [1619932653,1784.12]];
curr_time = myObj[0][0];
var result = [];
result.push(myObj[0])
for (i = 1; i < myObj.length; i++) {
  if (myObj[i][0] - curr_time > 60) {
    result.push(myObj[i]);
    curr_time = myObj[i][0];
  }  
}
console.log('result', result);
```